# Git: Invalid argumente directory

Tags: git, github

I am using the git bash in windows, originally my project is fine, but in a sudden, it throws an error when I want to pull from github.

My output of the console is as follow:

```
Rico@RICO-PC /h/SeatFinder_backup (master)
$ git pull origin master
From github.com:ricocmc/SeatFinder
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
': Invalid argumente directory at 'WebSite/dist/MCP/
```

Do any one have hints on what the problem is?

Comment: What does git status say after the error?

Comment: is there a quote (`'`) the beginning of the name of your `Website` directory ? this could confuse Git

Comment: my directory didn't have (') in the beginning, the name of the folder is Simply "WebSite", pure text

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help.

I finally find the cause, I have a file name "\r" in the git repository. It works fine in both linux and unix. But since windows is not supporting this type of file name, so the checkout is fail~

So if other people who see this and also got this kind of error, you may start to check your file names in that directory, make sure file names is suitable for other operating systems.